# Como Adicionar uma Mensagem de Erro antes de Deletar um item de um ListBox no Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8-1

Grande mestres, estou eu aqui novamente em busca de conhecimento. Tenho uma pequena aplicação em Windows Phone 8.1, com um banco de dados SQLite, conforme tela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ao selecionar o item no ListBox, e clicar no botão Excluir, fosse disparada uma mensagem perguntando se o usuário deseja relamente deletar estes dados. O código do botão Excluir, fica conforme abaixo:

```
    private async void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var excluir = ltbExibir.SelectedItem as Moto;
        excluir.mot_nome = txtNomeMoto.Text;
        excluir.mot_placa = txtPlacaMoto.Text;
        await conexao.DeleteAsync(excluir);            
    }
```

E aproveitando o ensejo, gostaria de saber como inserir título nas colunas do ListBox. No aguardo de vossas valiosas informações.

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir uma caixa de dialogo no Windows Phone 8.1 você deve utilizar a classe [`Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208674?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Você pode adicionar um título, uma mensagem e para o Windows Phone 8.1 ela permite que você adicione no máximo 2 botões.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de utilização:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Crie uma instância da classe MessageDialog passando a mensagem e o título da mensagem
    MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("C# melhor linguagem! Você concorda né?", "Oi oi oi!");

    // Adicione os botões desejados e configure os eventos para cada um
    msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Sim", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandlers)));
    msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Não", new UICommandInvokedHandler(CommandHandlers)));

    // Exibe a MessageDialog
    await msg.ShowAsync();
}

public void CommandHandlers(IUICommand commandLabel)
{
    // A verificação de qual botão foi pressionado pelo usuário só pode ser feita dessa forma
    var action = commandLabel.Label;
    switch (action)
    {
        case "Sim":
            // Faça alguma coisa pra alegrar o usuário, ele deu a resposta certa
            break;

        case "Não":
            // Reposta errada, faça alguma outra coisa
            break;
    }
}
```

Já sobre as múltiplas colunas no `ListView`, isso só será possível através de um `DataTemplate` customizado para o `ListView.ItemTemplate` e os títulos das colunas teriam que ser feito por fora do controle. Isso acontece porque o controle `ListView` não foi feito para exibir dados num formato de "tabela".

Answer (score -1):

**Solução para Silverlight**

Você deve usar o MessageBox para isso da seguinte maneira:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Deseja continuar?", "Opção", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    //Logica
}
```

**Solução para WinRT**

```
MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Sua mensagem", "Titulo");

//OK Button
UICommand okBtn = new UICommand("OK");
okBtn.Invoked = OkBtnClick;
msgDialog.Commands.Add(okBtn);

//Cancel Button
UICommand cancelBtn = new UICommand("Cancel");
cancelBtn.Invoked = CancelBtnClick;
msgDialog.Commands.Add(cancelBtn);

//Show message
msgDialog.ShowAsync();
```

E criar o métodos de chamada dos botões:

```
private void CancelBtnClick(IUICommand command)
{
}

private void OkBtnClick(IUICommand command)
{
}
```

Comment: Não existe MessageBox.Show para aplicações WinRT. Não saia por aí escrevendo qualquer baboseira. Pra falar a verdade, até existe, se o AP tivesse especificado que estava utilizando Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

Comment: Não escrevi nenhuma "baboseira", realmente me equivoquei mostrando a solução apenas para silverlight sem saber se o app dele é nesse formato.

Comment: Ok ok, SÓ ACHO, que se você realmente **soubesse** o que estava escrevendo, não teria cometido esse "equivoco".

Comment: Vamos respeitar as respostas, mesmo sendo equivocada, o intuito foi ajudar.